# How to list all nearest scheduled jobs in bacula bconsole

Tags: linux, bacula

Is there a way to see all scheduled jobs in bconsol?. You can see the first 30 jobs by executing `status dir` command in bconsole but how to list all (all nearest). I don't want to see scheduled jobs for all month only all the nearest scheduled jobs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the current bacula console manual](http://bacula.org/5.2.x-manuals/en/console/console/Bacula_Console.html#SECTION00250000000000000000):

> If you do a status dir, it will by default list the first occurrence
>   of all jobs that are scheduled today and tomorrow. If you wish to see
>   the jobs that are scheduled in the next three days (e.g. on Friday you
>   want to see the first occurrence of what tapes are scheduled to be
>   used on Friday, the weekend, and Monday), you can add the days=3
>   option. Note, a days=0 shows the first occurrence of jobs scheduled
>   today only. If you have multiple run statements, the first occurrence
>   of each run statement for the job will be displayed for the period
>   specified.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the command `status director`.  Here you can see that JOBA, JOBB, JOBC, JOBD and BackupCatalog are coming.

```
*st dir
localhost-dir Version: 9.0.6 (20 November 2017) x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu redhat Enterprise 8.1
Daemon started 06-Sep-23 10:28, conf reloaded 06-Sep-2023 16:26:26
 Jobs: run=5, running=1 mode=0,0
 Heap: heap=147,456 smbytes=225,707 max_bytes=253,153 bufs=648 max_bufs=908
 Res: njobs=8 nclients=3 nstores=1 npools=3 ncats=1 nfsets=9 nscheds=4

Scheduled Jobs:
Level          Type     Pri  Scheduled          Job Name           Volume
===================================================================================
Differential   Backup    10  07-Sep-23 21:00    JOBA               BGC007L6
Differential   Backup    10  07-Sep-23 21:00    JOBB               BGC007L6
Differential   Backup    11  07-Sep-23 21:00    JOBC               BGC007L6
Full           Backup    10  07-Sep-23 23:59    JOBD               BGC007L6
Full           Backup    11  08-Sep-23 06:10    BackupCatalog      BGC007L6
====
```

(...)